# Mostrar elementos repetidos en una lista

Tags: java, array, repetidos

tengo la siguiente duda, soy nuevo en esto de la programación y no me está dando un poco de problemas este código en java, necesito ingresar elementos a una lista y cuando ingrese uno repetido el programa diga que el dato ingresado esta repetido y muestre una lista de los elementos ya ingresados y se cierre.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> animales = new ArrayList<>();
    animales.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese un animal"));
        do{ 
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Ingrese un animal");
                     Collections.sort(animales);
                                          
       }while(animales == animales);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Ha ingresado un animal repetido");
                  Collections.sort(animales);
                      System.out.println("Lista es igual a "+animales);
                        break;
                }
}
```

Comment: ¿No crees que es mejor ordenar la lista cuando termines de cargar los elementos?

Comment: usa el método contains()

Comment: `showConfirmDialog` regresa un i`int`, prueba mejor con `showInputDialog`, nunca estás agregando el animal al `arraylist`

Answer (score 0):

Mira estos ejercicios son para que pongas en practica el conocimiento y la logica
hay muchas formas de resolver esto, no lo voy a detallar demasiado pero te voy a dejar un codigo para que lo analises, lo mejores y adaptes a como mejor te convenga.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    ArrayList<String> animales = new ArrayList<String>();
    Boolean esRepetido = false;
    do{
        String nombreAnimal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el nombre del animal");
        if(animales.contains(nombreAnimal)){
            esRepetido = true;
        }else{
            animales.add(nombreAnimal);
        }
    }while(!esRepetido);
    
    String strArregloAnimales = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < animales.size(); i++) {
        strArregloAnimales += "[" + animales.get(i) + "]";      
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strArregloAnimales);
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda , la verdad si me saco de varias dudas. Saludos !